# [奨学金]{しょうがくきん} and Repayment

Tags: words

**背景**

現在特任講師として大学機関で働いていますが、かつて院生のころから、日本人の「奨学金」の使い方が気になっていました。私は文部科学省の奨学金も頂きましたが、その奨学金は普通の英語の"scholarship"のように、返済しなくてもよいものでした。

しかし、院生として学んだ大学、また今教えている大学の日本人学生は、返済しなければならないものにも「奨学金」ということばを使っています。参考として、多分、[JASSOからもらっているもの](http://www.jasso.go.jp/henkan/faq_henkan.html)と思います。

**質問本体**

[辞書でちょっと調べたの](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/35351/m0u/%E5%A5%A8%E5%AD%A6/)で、一応分かっているつもりですが、次の三つの点についてお聞きしたいです。

1. 区別するため、表現を変えなければなりませんか。（例えば、「返済する奨学金」または「返済しない奨学金」のように言いますか）
2. 概念として、「奨学金」というと、返済するもの、と思いますか。
3. "scholarship"より"student aid"に意味が近いと思いますか。

**お詫び**

文法ミスが多くて読みづらいかもしれませんが、すみません。英語で答えてくれても構いません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

日本語の「奨学金」は、返済が必要なものと、必要でないものの、両方を指します。

- 「返済が必要な奨学金」＝「貸与型の奨学金」
- 「返済不要の奨学金」＝「給付型の奨学金」

といった言い方で区別しています。JASSOがやっているのは、すべて「貸与型」の方ですが、別の団体から返済不要な奨学金をもらっている人も、たくさんいます。

なお、返済が必要な奨学金の中にも、「利子付きの奨学金」「利子なしの奨学金」の2種類があります。

確かに「利子付きの奨学金」は、「教育ローン」や「借金」と非常に似ており、人によってはほとんど同一視していると思います。ただし一応、JASSOの奨学金は非営利事業であり、ローンは営利目的の金融商品である、という違いはあると思います。

参考： [教育費を借りるなら奨学金？教育ローン？](http://allabout.co.jp/gm/gc/12140/)
奨学金も返済するものなの？ じゃあ教育ローンとはどこが違うの？ 奨学金には返済不要のものもあったはず……これらの疑問にお答えします。